# PHP parse xml get specific value

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I has xml like :

```
<emps>
    <emp name="john">
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>20</age>
    </emp>
    <emp name="david">
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>25</age>
    </emp>
    <emp name="marry">
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>22</age>
    </emp>
    <emp name="tom">
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>28</age>
    </emp>
    <emp name="daisy">
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>24</age>
    </emp>
</emps>
```

This code used for get all emp detail:

```
$url = "abcd.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$url") or die("Error");
foreach($xml->children() as $emp) {
    $name = $emp[name];
    $gender = $emp->gender;
    $age = $emp->age;
    $detail .= $name . $gender . $age;
}
```

With that code, i can get all emp detail.

But, now i want get only emp detail from emp(2) to emp(4) in xml file, that mean i want to get detail of "david, marry, tom".

How to do it?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always treat elements like `<emp>` as an array, so a simple alternative is to use a `for()` loop and just pick out the element your after.  (Note that the array elements start at 0, so the for loop starts at 1 for the second element)...

```
$url = "abcd.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$url") or die("Error");
$detail = "";
//foreach($xml->children() as $emp) {
for ( $i = 1; $i<4; $i++ )  {
    $emp = $xml->emp[$i];
    $name = $emp['name'];
    $gender = $emp->gender;
    $age = $emp->age;
    $detail .= $name . $gender . $age;
}
echo $detail;
```

I've also fixed a couple of minor issues ( adding quotes in `['name']` and initialising `$detail`).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter for positions in Xpath. Be aware that the position in Xpath start with 1:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('emp[position() >= 2 and position() <= 4]') as $emp) {
    var_dump((string)$emp['name']);
}
```

Output:

```
string(5) "david" 
string(5) "marry" 
string(3) "tom"
```